# Hide H1 Title using the_title filter

Tags: filters, hooks, title, post-meta, get-the-title

I am trying to hide the pages H1 header IF a custom field specifies this.

On a page back end I have added a custom field:
Name = hide_title
Value = true

I then want to hide only the H1 using a filter.

The following code does not work but is the result of my noodling around. Can anyone suggest a fix for this code or an alternate way of approaching this. I do not want to amend the core template files.

Thanks

```
    // Hide H1 Title

    add_filter('the_title', 'hide_title', 10, 2);

    function hide_title($title, $id) {

        global $post;
        $key = 'hide_title';
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);

        if ($meta = 'true') $title['post_title'] = '';
        return $title;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the way your theme uses `the_title`, hooking into the `the_title` filter may or may not hide the title h1. What theme are you using?

The `the_title` filter passes two arguments: the title (string) and the post ID. Therefore, treating the title as an array (it looks like you're assuming `$title` is an array of post data, trying to set `$title['post_title']`. To have `the_title` return an empty string if the custom field "hide_title" is not empty, the following would suffice:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse145940_hide_hidden_title', 10, 2 );

function wpse145940_hide_hidden_title( $title, $postid ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'hide_title', true ) ) {
        $title = '';
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Using Woothemes Canvas. Worked perfectly. Made one alteration:     if ( get_post_meta( $postid, 'hide_title', true ) == 'true' ) {
So that the value of the custom field had to be true (rather than just existing). Thanks